# use of a propane fire table under a porch overhang, that meets up with an awning

Tags: propane, fire-pit

Is it safe to use my propane table under my covered overhang, that is than met by a large overhead canvas awning.  Will it cause damage to my siding or ceiling?

Comment: General prudence says no, but the variables might matter: how high is the canvas above the table? What is the output of the table? Do you have a way of measuring temperatures at the canvas while the table is operating? Does the canvas have a coating of any kind (polyurethane or otherwise) or is it raw cotton fabric?

Comment: Are the sides/front of porch open or have walls/windows?  Need to be aware of CO build up in closed places.   Distance from siding/covering should be the same as your hand stays nicely warm from it.  Sides and top.

Comment: How many btu is the table? Some are more decorative than a heat source. If the btu value is less than 20k maybe even larger.  I would try it and make sure the tarp is not over heating. I use a barbecue under my overhang but it is at the edge and it is +40k and probably taller than the table.

Comment: Just an assumption, but I would guess if you asked your insurance company or local fire department  they would tell you no.